# REST API Limits documentation/explanation, specifically 'PermissionSets' -> 'CreateCustom'?

Tags: rest-api, permission-sets, documentation

For the most part I can use common sense and deduce Salesforce's REST Api limits. For example, "DailyWorkflowEmails" = "Daily workflow emails" and "DailyAsyncApexExecutions" = "Daily asynchronous Apex method executions (batch Apex, future methods, queueable Apex, and scheduled Apex)"...

However I wanted to further understand some of the data - I couldn't find it specifically called out in in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_limits.htm)...

Specifically the 'CreateCustom' within the 'PermissionSets'. Any idea the differences between these two?

[image: PermissionSets - CreateCustom]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'PermissionSets' are how many Permission Sets are in the org (Note: standard permission sets that come with manage packages count against you in this respect.)

The 'CreateCustom' is simply the Custom Permissions within a particular created permission set. Below is a screenshot and Salesforce's documentation around these:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=perm_sets_custom_perms.htm&type=5
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_perms_overview.htm&type=5

[image]

However I see that there are two sObjects in the system called CustomPermission and CustomPermissionDependency - which has 0 records in my org. However I'm curious as to why that differs from the 88 the REST API says that I used up. I'll specifically ask Salesforce Support this and post back.